# XmlSerializerInputFormatter deprecated, what's the replacement?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a new .NET Core 2.1 web API that needs to receive data from older systems that are sending XML.  However, when I add the formatter, I'm getting the warning that it's been deprecated.

I can't change the legacy system, how do I accept XML?

I get the warning in ConfigureServices

```
config.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerInputFormatter());
```

Comment: As the duplicate shows, use the constructor that accepts `options`

Comment: Thanks, I guess my google-fu failed me when I searched for "deprecated" instead of "obsolete".